# change the Statistics and number of bins in Histograms in SQL

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Is there any way to change the number of Bins (Steps) of Histograms in SQL?
on the other hand, I want to change the number of rows for sampling in creating histogram by SQL after creating a statistic:

1. how can I See it?
   for example I create this Satistic:

   CREATE STATISTICS Customer_Lastname
   ON dbo.Customer (LastName)
   with sample 1 percent;

   when I write the query :
   DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("Customer",Customer_Lastname);
   although it has to show me 400 rows in Rows sample field it shows
   me the whole number of rows(40000))
2. How can I force SQL to use that Statistic?

Thanks

Comment: 1. May be the statistic was auto updated with default sample size since its creation.
2. If we were talking about index statistics, you would force the engine to use these statistics using the force index hint.

Comment: Actually, my aim is to force the engine to use only for example 5 percent of the whole table for creating statistics is there any way to do this? also is there any way to change the number of steps that sql constructs in histograms? would you give me sample queries?

Comment: Could you share the initial task for what purposes is it necessary?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean?